# Deleting data from Core Data table prior to api call not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Swift to populate core data from an API call in my viewDidLoad function.  My problem is that every visit to the page will call the service again and result in duplicate data.

I've tried clearing the Core Data database before retrieving the API results, but my code doesn't work.

So...

1. Is clearing the table prior to calling the API the best approach?
2. Can you show me a way to clear the data that works, the sample I've found doesn't do anything.

This is my code to delete the core data db:

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Job")
var mylist = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
mylist?.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
managedObjectContext.save(nil)
```

Thanks...

Comment: The best way to delete every record in Core Data is to just erase the database file and make a new one.

Comment: Does that not degrade performance, deleting and recreating the db on every visit to the page ?

Comment: Deleting a single file is faster than deleting 10 objects in a database. And you have to re-insert all the objects anyway, so there is no difference in performance for that part.

Comment: Obviously if you have other things in the database it's not an option, but you could split those out into a separate database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are just removing them from the returned array.  You need to delete each item in the array from Core Data.

```
...
for item: AnyObject in mylist {
   managedObjectContext.deleteObject(item as NSManagedObject)
}
managedObjectContext.save(nil)
```

Comment: Oh, I thought that's what removeall did?

Comment: `executeFetchRequest` returns an Array of your Entity items that match the fetch request.  `removeAll` is a method of Array and not any part of Core Data.